# Displaying labels in the same row

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code

```
<div style="display:inline" >
    <div>
        <label>NOM:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ben felten</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got this result:

[image: im1]

I need to change my code to get a result like this :

[image: im2]

I need the two labels displayed in the same line and each `div` (parent to each `label`) having a width of 50 percent of the page's width.

1. How can i change my snipet to  do that?

Thanks

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/mht9m/3/) Since they are in different `div`'s use `display: inline-block` on them. Or float them: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/mht9m/1/)

Comment: When you say "each div has width 50% of page width", which div are you talking about, the one with "nom" or the one with the "ben felten"?

Comment: @MarcAudet twice like in the second picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
  <div style="display:inline" >
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
            <label>NOM:</label>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
            <label>Ben felten</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `div`s are `block` elements by default, you do not need `display: block;`.

Comment: Thanks mate you saved my time :P love you!!

Answer (score 2):

You need display inline for more than just the parent div.

```
div{
  display:inline;
}

label{
  display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVH5C/

Answer (score 2):

add a class to your main div:

```
<div class="main">
    <div >
        <label>NOM:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ben felten</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```
.main div{width: 50%; float: left;}
```

Or if those inside `divs` are realy there just for the labels there's no need for them to exist and you can style the labels directly, like:

```
<div class="main">
    <label>NOM:</label>
    <label>Ben felten</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main label{display: block; width: 50%; float: left;}
```

Comment: Whats with `.main{position:relative;}`?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="label-container">
        <label>NOM:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="label-container">
        <label  >Ben felten</label>
    </div>
    <div class="labels-end"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.labels-end{
    clear: both;
}
div.label-container{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RsK5N/3/

Div "labels-end" is not mandatory if labels spread over the entire width like in this case.
Without extra `clear: both` styled `div` browser will try to put the latter content in the same line as your labels. So it works without this div but **only** because there is no more width available.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use inline-blocks and table-cells as follows.

**Using inline-blocks**

```
<div class="ex1">
    <label>NOM:</label><label>Ben felten</label>
</div>


div.ex1 {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    width: auto; /* will take the width of parent (page) container */
}
div.ex1 label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: beige;
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Using CSS table-cells**

```
<div class="ex2">
    <label>NOM:</label><label>Ben felten</label>
</div>

div.ex2 {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    width: 100%; /* will take the width of parent (page) container */
    display: table;
}
div.ex2 label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

If you use inline blocks, you need to be careful about any white space between the two `label` elements since any white space will add to the width of the line and will cause the second `label` to wrap to a second line.  Use `vertical-align: top` to get rid of the extra white space below the labels which arises because of the inline formatting.

The extra white space issue does not arise with table-cells.  Use `width: 100%` on the table div to make it fill up the width of the parent container (`auto` gives a shrink-to-fit width).

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Nb24q/

**Comment:** You don't need to wrap the `label` elements in `div` unless you need them for some other reason.